# ASP.NET MVC : removing a specific row from a table with model.state

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, modelstate

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC; I'm trying to create a dynamic table with buttons that add/remove rows when clicked using model states and not jQuery, so right now my page words but I was only able to create a button that removes the last added row and I really want a way to remove a specific row from my table by adding the "remove" option to table data.

Here's the code I have right now that is working and removing the last added row.

View

```
@{ for (int i = 0; i < Model.ValueModel.Count; i++)
{
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr id="Row">
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ValueModel[i].id, new SelectList(Model.ReplaceModel, "id", "Name"))
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ValueModel[i].value)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
       }
}

<button name="submit" value="AddLine"> Add Line </button>
<button name="submit" value="RemLine"> Remove Line </button>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(TestModel model, string submit)
{       
        switch (submit)
        {
            case "AddLine":
                model.ValueModel.Add(new ValueModel());
                break;

            case "RemLine":
                if (model.ValueModel.Count > 0)
                {
                    model.ValueModel.RemoveAt(model.ValueModel.Count - 1);
                }
        }             
        return View(model);
}
```

The code works with my models which are not important for the question what I want to learn is a way to remove the line by adding it to a third `<td>` in the view and using a similar action to

```
model.ValueModel.RemoveAt(model.ValueModel.Count - 1);
```

from the switch case "RemLine".

Something like this

```
@{ for (int i = 0; i < Model.ValueModel.Count; i++)
{
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr id="Row">
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ValueModel[i].id, new SelectList(Model.ReplaceModel, "id", "Name"))
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ValueModel[i].value)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button name="submit" value="RemLine"> Remove Line </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
       }
}

<button name="submit" value="AddLine"> Add Line </button>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(TestModel model, string submit)
{       
        switch (submit)
        {
            case "AddLine":
                model.ValueModel.Add(new ValueModel());
                break;

            case "RemLine":
                if (model.ValueModel.Count > 0)
                {
                    model.ValueModel.**BegoneLine**(The line in which the button is);
                }
        }             

        return View(model);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a row id with your 'remove' button and then read it in your controller. You can add buttons like this (per row):

```
<button name="submit" value="@(i)">Remove row</button>
...
<button name="submit" value="@(i)">Remove row</button>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Test(TestModel model, string submit)
 {
     switch (submit)
    {
        case "AddLine":
            model.ValueModel.Add(new ValueModel());
            break;

        case "RemLine":
            if (model.ValueModel.Count > 0)
            {
                model.ValueModel.RemoveAt(model.ValueModel.Count - 1);
            }
            break;

        case string number when int.TryParse(number,out var index):
            if (model.ValueModel.Count > 0)
            {
                model.ValueModel.RemoveAt(index);
            }

            break;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but im afraid i cant/**don't know how** to apply the solution since right now the switch case is based on the name of the buttom, im really sorry but could you be a bit more specific in how to solve this ?

Comment: Thank you so much! i was finally able to understand what im supposed to do there, i didnt know i was able to create a switch case ln the controller ilke that, working with mvc can be so weird and i definitely have a lot to learn, again thank you, your answer really helped me, have a great week!